# Template for MIGX MODx

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, migx

I have some PHP foreach that i have moved to MIGX, now can somebody know how to make template for MIGX, here is my PHP

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$y = 0;
$active = 'active';
echo '<ol class="carousel-indicators">';
foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {
 if ($i < 1) {
  echo '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' . $i . '" class="active"></li>';
  $i = $i + 1;
 }
 else {
  echo '
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' . $i . '"></li>';
  $i = $i + 1;
 }
}
echo '</ol>';
echo '<div class="carousel-inner">';
foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {
 $y = $y + 1;
 if ($y == 1) {
  echo '
  <div class="' . $active . ' item">
    <img class="img_book" src="' . $file . '" alt="">
  </div>
  ';
 }
 else {
  $active = 'not-active';
  echo '
  <div class="' . $active . ' item">
    <img class="img_book" src="' . $file . '" alt="">
  </div>
  ';
 }
}
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIGX Extra comes with a Snippet `getImageList` that will parse the values in the MIGX TV and return them based on a Chunk template that you specify.

For example, you could put this snippet call in your Template:

```
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        [[getImageList? 
            &tvname=`myMIGXtv`
            &tpl=`myTplChunk`
        ]]
    </div>
```

The snippet would return the values stored in the MIGX TV named `myMIGXtv`, in the currently requested Resource, and format the output based on the tpl Chunk names `myTplChunk`. The content of `myTplChunk` would be something like:

```
    <div class="[[+idx:is=`1`:then=`active`:else=``]] item">
        <img class="img_book" src="[[+file]]" alt="[[+another_migx_field]]">
    </div>
```

The syntax of calling the `[[+idx]]` placeholder with a `:` after the tag name, invokes the MODX output modifier class, which supports conditionals.

Here are some reference materials for the methods described above:

- [Documentation for MIGX getImageList](https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/migx/migx.frontend-usage)
- [Documentation for MODX
  Output Modifiers](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/input-and-output-filters-(output-modifiers))
- [The right way and wrong way to use conditional
  MODX Output Modifiers](http://modx.com/blog/2012/09/14/tags-as-the-result-or-how-conditionals-are-like-mosquitoes/)